# PropType for Object Where Keys are IDs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I'm refactoring my redux stores to be objects where the keys are IDs instead of arrays. Example:

Old:

```js
const orders = [
  { id: a, user: 1, items: ['apple','orange'] },
];
```

New:

```js
const orders = {
  a: { user: 1, items: ['apple','orange'] },
};
```

It was easy enough to specify the PropTypes for orders previously, but dunno how to change it now that it's an object of dynamic keys, but I want to validate each individual order.

```js
order: PropTypes.arrayOf({
  PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    user: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    items: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string).isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
}).isRequired,
```

How would I change my PropTypes to match the new structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From  prop-types docs

```
// An object with property values of a certain type
  optionalObjectOf: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.number),
```

so this should work

```
orders: PropTypes.objectOf(
  PropTypes.shape({
    user: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    items: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string).isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
).isRequired,
```

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types#usage)

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  order: function(props, propName, componentName) {
    if (typeof props[propName] !== 'string') { // check if its ID
      return new Error(
        'Invalid prop `' + propName + '` supplied to' +
        ' `' + componentName + '`. Validation failed.'
      );
    }
    // add more checks for order.user, order.items, etc.
  }
}
```

Or you can use some other checking like: string length, mongoose objectId, etc.